# Question about domestic tolls in India was wrongly closed as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, vote-to-close, duplicates

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76533/41775) was marked (or closed?) as a duplicate of [this question.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10990/41775)

But it's not a duplicate at all. The marked question is about toll regulations *domestically* in India, *not involving any foreign countries.*

The one that it's marked as a duplicate of is about bringing stuff *into India from abroad.*

Clearly the two questions are completely different.

According to [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/321647) it looks like OP may have themselves caused it to be closed? Is that what happened?

In either case, it's not a duplicate of that question. Can we have it re-opened and the duplicate tag removed?

Comment: It's mad how much time this community ends up spending, explaining why two questions aren't duplicates, to closevoters who didn't even take the time to read them before voting :-( it's been raised heaps of times on meta, but they just don't care. Thanks for flagging it

Comment: @user568458 On the brighter side, though, I think this question was closed by only one vote from one user, and from OP (who is a new user and therefore might not have understood fully what was going on.) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's open again now :)